# Sonata admin-bundle - haven't logout nav bar

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, logout, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I have installed Sonata-admin-bundle 3.x with User-bundle and FOSUserBundle. Mostly all of this stuff is working great but in admin panel the logout button is missing.The logout button show in the footer in DEV environment but not in PROD. Anyone knows how to add the logout button to upper navigation bar in the top right corner ? Can someone help me ?

```
 {% block user_block %}
    {% if app.user %}
        {% set _bg_class          = "bg-light-blue" %}
        {% set _logout_uri        = url('sonata_user_admin_security_logout') %}
        {% set _logout_text       = 'user_block_logout'|trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') %}
        {% set _profile_uri       = sonata_user.userAdmin.isGranted('EDIT', app.user) ? sonata_user.userAdmin.generateUrl('edit', {id: sonata_user.userAdmin.id(app.user)}) : sonata_user.userAdmin.generateUrl('show', {id: sonata_user.userAdmin.id(app.user)}) %}
        {% set _profile_text      = 'user_block_profile'|trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') %}
        {% set _user_image        = sonata_user.defaultAvatar ? asset(sonata_user.defaultAvatar) : null %}
        {# Customize this with your profile picture implementation, see below for example #}
        {#{% set _user_image  = app.user.profilePicture|default(asset(sonata_user.defaultAvatar)) %}#}

        {% if is_granted('ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN') and sonata_user.impersonating %}
            {% set _bg_class    = "bg-light-green" %}
            {% set _logout_uri  = url(sonata_user.impersonating.route, sonata_user.impersonating.parameters| merge({'_switch_user': '_exit'})) %}
            {% set _logout_text = 'switch_user_exit'|trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') %}
        {% endif %}

        <li class="user-header {{ _bg_class }}">
            {% if _user_image %}
                <img src="{{ _user_image }}" class="img-circle" alt="Avatar" />
            {% endif %}
            <p>{{ app.user }}</p>
        </li>{
        <li class="user-body">

        </li>}<li class="user-footer">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <a href="{{ _profile_uri }}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ _profile_text }}</a>
            </div>

            <div class="pull-right">
                <a href="{{ _logout_uri }}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> {{ _logout_text }}</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In your page, the logout uri is defined as `<a href="{{ _logout_uri }}">...</a>`. The real url is `url('sonata_user_admin_security_logout')`. Just copy/paste where you need it to be ?

Comment: ok thanks for help :) but not that was key to me problem. I jut must customize user_block but in core-bundle.

Answer (score 2):

To see the logout  button you need to assign the role

> ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN

to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the role `ROLE_ADMIN` assigned to your user, e.g. within his role hierarchy in your `security.yml`.

I had the exact same problem, and this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to check or set sonata admin role in configuration ([Sonata Admin Bundle Configuration Reference](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/reference/configuration.html)):

```
sonata_admin:
    security:
        role_admin: ROLE_SUPER_DUPER_ADMIN
```

By default it is `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN`.

Then don't forget to update role hierarchy in `security.yaml` and set the corresponding role to the user.